# Fast execute of PDO query

Tags: mysql, pdo

Which is the fastest way to execute big `UPDATE` queries? Should I use `bindValue()`, `bindParam()`, `execute(array())` or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Use `execute(array())`.

Because it's *shortest*.

Comment: that reasoning is ad 1) nonsensical and ad 2) not even relevant to the question asked...